# Spacing after Enumerate

Tags: vertical-alignment, lists, enumerate

How can I remove the space after enumerated item and the next line in text ? I use following:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
    \item bi-axial etc. etc. 
    \item uni-axial etc. etc.
    \item uni-axial etc. etc.
    \item uni-axial etc. 
\end{enumerate}
%
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy with the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}
\begin{document}
Something.
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\item Two
\end{enumerate}
Something else.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to do it for the enumerate environment, then you can add this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{enumerate}{\vskip-\lastskip}
```

This adds a hook to the end of the enumerate environment which undoes the last glue which was placed on the page.

It needs to be done this way rather than with \unskip because the glue has already made its way to the main vertical list (see TeX by Topic pg. 96).

Comment: Thanks, Is there also a way to remove the spacing after table and figure ?

Comment: Try the same hook with the environment you're using for tables and figures. By the way, this solution only removes the spacing after, not before.